# Find maximum value of specific variable among an array of Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I have an object called Student with variables student_id and grade. In the main class, I can set the values of student_id and grade. There's also an array in the main class called Classroom where I can store an instance of Student. I placed 4 instances of Student with different values of student_id and grade. 
Now, I want to return the value of student_id with the greatest grade.

I tried sorting the array Classroom using the code below.

```
Classroom.sort(key=lambda y: y.grades, reverse=True)
```

The object with the greatest grade is in the first element and lowest grade at the last element. With this, I can just return the first element always, but I don't want to rearrange the array.

I am also thinking of using max() but I don't think it works with objects. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Everything is an object in python so it's safe to say that `max()` does work on objects.

Comment: `max(Classroom.sort())` should return the largest grade in the list

Comment: There's no need to explicitly say sort classroom based on variable grade? But what if I have 5 more variables in Student class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted()` instead of `list.sort()`. The former creates a new, sorted list, while the latter sorts the existing array in place.

```py
>>> numbers = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted(numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(numbers)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> numbers.sort()
>>> print(numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But instead of taking the first element of `sorted()`, you can use `max()`, which takes a key argument, similar to how `sorted()` and `list.sort()` do.

```
max_student = max(Classroom, key=lambda y: y.grades)
```

Comment: there's an error after I changed .sort() to .sorted it says " 'list' object has no attribute 'sorted' "

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sorted` to solve this problem, but rather `max`. Anyways, `sorted` isn't a method on a list object, but rather a function you pass your list into. i.e. `sorted(your_list)` instead of `your_list.sorted()`.

Comment: max(Classroom, key=lambda y: y.grades) returns the maximum grade right? but I want to return student_id with the greatest grade

Comment: also, when I used
    max(Classroom, key=lambda y: y.grades)
it displays something like "... object at 0x0000018B5B429F98"

Comment: It will return the student with the maximum grade, which you can then access the `student_id` attribute of.

Comment: thank you so much for helping @raindrop. I already posted a snippet that already works. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

this worked in my code:

```
BestStudent = max(Classroom, key=lambda y: y.grades).student_id
```

Thank you so much for helping everyone.